# Why isn't gpio_set_debounce working in my Raspberry Pi Zero kernel module?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, pi-zero, modules, interrupts

I'm stuck on [example 1 from this tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds#Example_1_Button_Press_LED_Light_LKM). I found the Raspberry Pi code for it [here](https://github.com/derekmolloy/exploringrpi/blob/master/chp16/gpio/gpio_test.c). I uncommented the `gpio_set_debounce` line and compiled the module, but my switch still bounces a ton, resulting in dozens of interrupt calls per switch press. I tried it with and without a pulldown resistor and I get the same result.

My kernel headers version is `linux-headers-4.4.13+`.

Can someone try this out and see if they get the same result on their Pi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [header](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.4.y/include/linux/gpio.h) it appears `gpio_set_debounce` isnt actually implemented which would explain why your code changes didnt make a difference

```
static inline int gpio_set_debounce(unsigned gpio, unsigned debounce)
{
    return -ENOSYS;
}
```

Try checking/printing the return value of your call to verify it is indeed so. (I wasnt able to find the headers for the exact kernel version you have mentioned).

## Update on how I traced

The linux kernel source code cross reference is available [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com).
The Raspbian version [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/) should be mostly the same.
I searched for [gpio_set_debounce](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.4;i=gpio_set_debounce)
on the linux cross reference site and traced the following sequence

`include/linux/gpio.h` conditionally includes `asm-generic/gpio.h` or `asm/gpio.h` but also
provides a default implementation (returning -ENOSYS) as fallback in case there is no 
specialization for the particular chip/device.

```
static inline int gpio_set_debounce(unsigned gpio, unsigned debounce)
{
    return -ENOSYS;
}
```

This is what i had mentioned previously

Looking at `include/asm-generic/gpio.h` one should see

```
 static inline int gpio_set_debounce(unsigned gpio, unsigned debounce)
 {
    return gpiod_set_debounce(gpio_to_desc(gpio), debounce);
 }
```

`gpiod_set_debounce` is declared in `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.h` and implemented in `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c`

like so

```
int gpiod_set_debounce(struct gpio_desc *desc, unsigned debounce)
{
         struct gpio_chip        *chip;

         if (!desc || !desc->chip) {
                 pr_warn("%s: invalid GPIO\n", __func__);
                 return -EINVAL;
         }

         chip = desc->chip;
         if (!chip->set || !chip->set_debounce) {
                 gpiod_dbg(desc,
                           "%s: missing set() or set_debounce() operations\n",
                           __func__);
                 return -ENOTSUPP;
         }

         return chip->set_debounce(chip, gpio_chip_hwgpio(desc), debounce);
}
```

from @Jason's comment below I believe `return -ENOTSUPP;` is the value being returned indicating there is no implementation/support.

the file `asm/gpio.h` specific to arm looks like [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/gpio.h?v=4.4;a=arm) where there isnt a specialization either.

Comment: That's what the function looks like in my `gpio.h`, but `gpio_direction_output` has the same body and when I call that function on a pin with an LED connected to it (and pass 1 to the `value` parameter), the LED lights up.

Comment: So `gpio_set_debounce` returned -524 which, according to [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.4.y/include/linux/errno.h), stands for "Operation is not supported". That explains my issue. However, why does the `gpio_direction_output` function have the same body, yet it returns 0 and actually has an effect on the pin?

Comment: (re)traced and found the following sequence in
`/include/asm-generic/gpio.h` , `/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.h` , `drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c`

`gpio_set_debounce` in `gpio.h` calls `gpiod_set_debounce` in `gpiolib.h` which is implemented in `gpiolib.c` lines 1210 - 1229
`gpio_direction_output` in `gpio.h` calls `gpiod_direction_output_raw` declared in `gpiolib.h` which is implemented in `gpiolib.c` lines 1120 - 1155
beyond that there seems to be a device specific implementation i couldn't find

Comment: @Jason if an answer worked for you, it would nice to accept it by clicking the tick mark near it.

Comment: How did you "(re)trace" it? I want to try that out. Also, I understand the voting system. However, as I pointed out in my second comment, there is another function in the same header file with the same body that is clearly implemented. Your answer's observation that "it appears `gpio_set_debounce` isn't actually implemented" based on the body of it is therefore inconclusive and might confuse another reader looking for similar help. If you remove that part of your answer and perhaps add an explanation of how you traced the functions, I'd be more willing to vote for it and possibly accept it.

Comment: @Jason In case it is not clear from S.M.'s gracious explication, a C/C++ function can have a placeholder implementation that via preprocessor directives is overridden in an actual build; here evidently the override for `gpio_direction_output()` is meaningful in a way that `gpio_set_debounce()` is not.   Since debouncing is simple to implement in software at any level, I'd take this to mean that the BCM hardware likely doesn't have any such feature, so it is left up to "higher level software" (whereas obviously the hardware must implement setting direction to output).